# Laravel 5.4 Update Existing Records in Pivot Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an existing pivot table in Laravel 5.4, which stores all the products, which belong to an order, called **order_product**

I'm using the "update()" method in my OrderController to update an order and update any products, which belong to the order.

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $order = Order::updateOrCreate(['woo_order_id' => $request->input('id')]);
    $order->woo_order_id = $request->input('id');
    $order->woo_order_date = $request->input('date_created');

    // loop through each item of the order and add to pivot table order_product
    //$order->products()->detach();
    foreach($request->input('line_items') as $item) 
    {
        $order->products()->updateExistingPivot($item['product_id'], [
            'order_id' => $request->input('id'),
            'qty'      => $item['quantity'],
        ], false);
    }
}
```

Once the order is created/updated I loop through each line item in the order to update any added/deleted/altered products in that order.

I've tried:

```
$order->products()->detach($item['product_id']); // inside the foreach loop
```

to delete all associated rows and re-write the updated rows to avoid a duplicate entry error and then run:

```
$order->products()->attach($item['product_id'], [
            'order_id' => $request->input('id'),
            'qty'      => $item['quantity'],
        ]);
```

I've also tried:

```
$order->products()->updateExistingPivot($item['product_id'], [
            'order_id' => $request->input('id'),
            'qty'      => $item['quantity'],
        ], false);
```

inside the foreach loop by itself, since this method only updates existing orders.

I've also tried adding:

```
$order->save($order);
```

which throws an error telling me I need to pass an array to the save() method.

I've run out of ideas what could possibly be wrong.

**UPDATE**

Using the sync() function also doesn't help.

```
$order->products()->sync([$item['product_id'] => [
            'order_id' => $request->input('id'),
            'qty'      => $item['quantity'],
        ]]);
```

Comment: What fields does your pivot table have?

Comment: @Don'tPanic order_id, product_id, qty, created_at, updated_at

Comment: And what does `Using the sync() function also doesn't help` mean?  Do you get any errors?  Bad data saved, no data saved ... ?

Comment: using sync() throws "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'order_id' cannot be null" The values it's being passed to are "values (2017-08-03 13:02:07, , 31, 2017-08-03 13:02:07)" I've tested the value of $request->input('id') and know that it contains the order ID value.

Comment: That's your problem then.  `sync` is the way to do what you need, but something is missing from the data you're passing it.

Comment: But why would sync() cause the order_id value to be null? If I log the value of $request->input('id') it correctly returns the order ID.

Comment: I don't think you need to add `order_id` to the array you are passing in, it should know what the order id is because it should be on the `$order` object you are starting out with.  You need to make sure you `$order->save()` before trying to attach products to it as well.  If it's not saved, the `id` will be null.

Comment: @user3158900 updateOrCreate() persists the data without the need to call the save() method. The attach() method works 100% when I first create records in that pivot table. $request->input('id') contains a value. It's not trying to reference a record that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need to create a new instance of your table on update pass it to your function as a parameter.
2. Use **sync** and **syncWithoutDetaching** wrapped in an if

Change your function as follows:

```
 public function update(Order $order,Request $request)
{
   $order::where('id',$order->id)([
   'woo_order_id' => $request->input('id'),
   'woo_order_date' => $request->input('date_created')
   ]);

   // loop through each item of the order and add to pivot table order_product
   $item = 0;
   foreach($request->input('line_items') as $item) 
   {

      if($item == 0){

         $order->products()->sync(

         $item['product_id'] => [
         'order_id' => $request->input('id'),
         'qty'      => $item['quantity'],
         ]);
      }
      else{

         $order->products()->syncWithoutDetaching(

         $item['product_id'] => [
         'order_id' => $request->input('id'),
         'qty'      => $item['quantity'],
         ]);

      }
      $i++;
   }
}
```

This should allow you to update without getting any duplicate records.